# How to move completed Panda into a excel file or a google sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, google-sheets, google-colaboratory

I have finished coding some pandas but I don't know what to do now. I want to export the pandas onto a google sheet or excel file so I can graph the data out using google data studio. Since I'm new to pandas, does anyone know how to move completed pandas onto an excel or google sheets file?

I tried searching for the answer using all the keywords and the entire question!  The closest I got gave me the result that: 
cp: cannot create regular file 'drive/My Drive/': No such file or directory

`Finished_Data.to_csv('Completed_Data.csv')`
`!cp Completed_Data.csv drive/My\ Drive/`

Most of the ways I tried didn't give me any results and just wasted my time.

Comment: *Most of the ways I tried didn't give me any results*.  It would be useful (and part of [ask]) to show us what you've tried, and describe the shortcomings or errors of those methods. Seems unlikely that they did not "give any results". If you tried something, it either did *something* (maybe not what you expected/wanted) or threw an error. That's information that someone could use to help you. Please include in your quesiton.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that in the future. Also, how did you make the code part look like code, instead of normal text?

Comment: four spaces to start each line, or select the block of text and Ctrl+K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if all you want to to is create an excel file you can use pandas.to_excel:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

**update**

> what’s the best way to save pd.dataframe object as a google sheet document

Google sheets provides an API. I'm not familiar with it but it seems well documented
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

> Is there something wrong with my code?
>   `export_excel = Finished.to_excel (r'C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Finished Pandas.xlsx', index = None, header=True)`

1. to_excel does not return anything. You don't need to assign it to a variable.
2. index is a boolean parameter. Set it to either True if you want your index to be exported or False if not.
   xlsx depends also on the libary openpyxl. What error message do you get?

Comment: If you don’t mind me asking, what’s the best way to save pd.dataframe object as a google sheet document or append to the one that already exists?

Comment: that is my exact question! I already tried looking at that link, but I still can't figure out how it's working! Here is my code:   export_excel = Finished.to_excel (r'C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Finished Pandas.xlsx', index = None, header=True) Is there something wrong with my code?